# Why is the idol of a lizard kept in front of the Divine Mother at Dakshineswar?

Tags: temple, tantra, kali

[image]

As the enclosed image shows, there is an idol of a golden lizard (svarna-godhika) to the left of Mother Bhavatarini at Dakshineswar.

What is the scriptural reason of this idol of lizard?

Comment: You must be knowing the reason here?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is related to some local tradition of Bengal.

In the Chandimangala written in Bengali, Devi Bhagavati assumed a godhA (big-sized lizard) Form.

In the images of Goddess Parvati built in the middle ages, godhA is frequently seen with Devi.

(Reference : Satramulak Bharatiya Shaktisadhana,Upendrakumar Das, RMIC, vol.1, page 110).